# Is their a way to auto login into t-mobile from a link or button?

Tags: asp.net

Helping a Friend on a web site he would like to have a button or a link that auto login into his t-mobile account is their a way to do so?

this is my first time using API any pointer would be great thank you.
i register at t-mobile however it does not show any documentation on api only web site i could find was in polish.

1) how do i get the api

2) how do i call it and consume the methods?

any help would be great thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access to the T-mobile API to access their data objects. You'll also need to register for their partner network before you can get access to it. Here is the link to the sign up page:

http://developer.t-mobile.com/site/global/home/p_home.jsp

Comment: k i sign up as a partner however i can't find the api.